# Left Join Linq Group by on Child table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have created a left join that populates a list; however, now I am trying to group by "Category" and Sum on "Volume" to summarize the data in a view in `ASP.NET MVC`.  The problem I am running into is that all the research I have done shows left joins where the grouped field originates from the parent table vs. the child table.  In this case I am attempting to pull in a Category by SicCode (from the Buckets table) to further summarize portfolio data (from the Portfolio table).  I want all data from the portfolio table and then bring a category in from the Buckets table to summarize.  The next step is to group on that category and populate summary data for users in the view.

I tried to add group on commands but it wouldn't work.

I appreciate your feedback.

Below is the code in the controller:

```
var LpAb = (from l in db.Portfolio
    join a in db.Buckets on l.SicCodeLP equals a.SicCode into t
    from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group rt by rt.Category into grouped
    select new
    {
        Category = rt.Category,
        TotalVolume = t.Sum(x => l.Volume)
    }).ToList();
```

Final Table should look like this (Columns are separated by "/").

Category/   Count/  Volume
•   Crops/      1   /384000
•   Professional/   1/  20465
•   Livestock/1/80155

Raw Data:

Portfolio class
Number/ Date/   Customer/   SicCodeLP/  Volume
1234/   31-Dec-16/  Customer /  191 /384000

Buckets class
SicCode/SicDetail/  Pool/   Category
191 /Farms & Crops/ 1/  Crops

Comment: *The next step is to group on that category* So where is `group ... by ...` in your query then? What's the issue?

Comment: Do you really need *outer* join if you want to group by `Category`? There may be a `null` group.

Comment: I had this group by statement in the code and it didn't work.  It listed all the records from the portfolio table but didn't group them.                                        var LpAb = (from l in db.LoanPortfolio
                        join a in db.AllowanceBuckets on l.SicCodeLP equals a.SicCode into t
                        from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        group rt by rt.Category into grouped

Comment: So put *that* in your question and tell where/why it failed.

Comment: Does a Portfolio have many Buckets or just one?  If a Portfolio has two buckets, do you want that porfolio counted twice in the result?

Comment: I added an update.  A portfolio will have one bucket assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could use the `let` keyword to hold a correlated subquery.

```
var LpAb = (
  from portfolio in db.Portfolio
  let category = db.Buckets
    .Where(b => l.SicCodeLP == b.SicCode)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Category ?? ""
  group portfolio by category into g
  select new {
    Category = g.Key,
    TotalVolume = g.Sum(porfolio => porfolio.Volume)
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together.  I am getting this error.  Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

This is on the bucket.Category ?? -1 into g row.